# In ASP.Net, where should I check the IdP in SAML SP to check if the user Logged out?

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, logout, saml-2.0

I want to implementing SAML P in a web application as a SAML Service Provider. I wonder how my application can know that a user X has logged out from the IdP?

I've read that the IdP might make a broadcast when the user logged out from the IdP directly or from any other SP but the IdP I'm using is not making any broadcast.

Should I redirect to the IdP in the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have heard right: The identity provider must send a LogoutRequest to all ServiceProviders in the session (on the log out URL that the SPs have registered with the IdP) - see page 37 of http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf. 
In SAML there is no other standard way for SPs to deterministically know of user logging out.

Have you registered your Logout URL with the IdP?

Comment: Not yet.. I'll check it.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine but it is sending a token in the query string named "SQMLRequest". but I'm not able to decode it although I used the same mechanism of decoding the SQML Login Response.

Any clue ?